# Java A Beginners Guide: FindFac & Nested Loops

Tags: java

In **Java A Beginners Guide 5th edition** a class, `FindFac`, uses nested loops to find factors between 2 and 100.

> ```
> package examples;
>
> public class FindFac {
>
>   public static void main(String args[]){
>
>    for(int i=2; i <= 100; i++) {
>         System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
>         for(int j=2; j < i; j++)
>             if((i%j) == 0) System.out.print(j + " ");
>         System.out.println();
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

It mentions:

> The preceding program can be made more efficient. Can you see how? (Hint: The number of iterations in the inner loop can be reduced)

To my knowledge it's hinting at 'j++', but I'm not sure how to improve the code.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop iteraters from 2 to i-1.

Assume i is 100 and j is 2. The inner loop in this code will iterate from 2 to 99.

But you just need to iterate till the sqrt of i that is 10.

This is because when you get one factor of i, say 5, 100/5 is another factor ie 20.

Hence by iterating till 10 in the inner loop you should get all the factors.

Comment: I know why you only need to do up to SQRT(i) for inner loop, but you don't explain it well enough where OP will be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This example changes the maximum iteration of J dynamically. We first initialize jMAX as i, and then iterates starting from 1, if it is a factor, then set jMAX as the result, for example, the factor of 10 is 2, the result is 5, we know that another factor cannot be between 5-10, since the divisor will be less than 2. After that, jMAX is reset to 100.

```
int jMAX;
for(int i=2; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
            jMAX = i;
            for(int j=1; j < jMAX; j++)
            {
                if((i%j) == 0) 
                    {
                        jMAX = i/j;
                        if(j!=jMAX){
                        System.out.print(j +" "+ jMAX+" ");
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.print(j+" ");
                        }
                    }
            }
            jMAX =100;

            System.out.println();
        }
```

number of iterations: 1950, which is 3000 iteration lesser

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
   Use nested loops to find factors of numbers
   between 2 and 100.
*/

class FindFac {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
      System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
      for(int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++)
        if((i % j) == 0) {
          System.out.print(j + " ");
          if((i/j) != j) System.out.print((i/j) + " ");
        }  
      System.out.println();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This reduced the number of iterations and also makes sure that factors greater than 9 are output as well for i-values that are greater than 10. Also, by adding the if((i/j) != ) statement the program checks against j-values to make sure that it does not repeat factors (i.e. 8*8=64)

Comment: maybe it is because of factors that get more value

Answer (score 0):

Just use `j <= i/2` in the inner loop.

Comment: Two other answers give a much better improvement.  If you think this is better, then you should explain how.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate as long as `j <= i/2` in the inner loop, not as long as `j < i`.

So for example, if `i = 12` then `j` can only be `<= 6` because if `j > 6`, then `i/j` will be smaller than 2, but 2 is the smallest result allowed to know if `j` is a factor.

The below outputs show either a dot or an acceptable factor for each iteration:

- When `j < i`:

> Factors of 2: 
>  Factors of 3: .
>  Factors of 4: 2.
>  Factors
>   of 5: ...
>  Factors of 6: 23..
>  Factors of 7: .....
>   Factors of 8: 2.4...
>  Factors of 9: .3.....
>  Factors of 10:
>   2..5....
>  Factors of 11: .........
>  Factors of 12: 234.6.....
>  Factors of 13: ...........
>  Factors of 14: 2....7......
>  Factors of 15: .3.5.........
>  Factors of 16: 2.4...8.......
>  Factors of 17: ...............
>  Factors of 18: 23..6..9........
>  Factors of 19: .................
>  Factors of 20: 2.45....10.........

- When j <= i/2:

> Factors of 2: 
>  Factors of 3: 
>  Factors of 4: 2
>  Factors
>   of 5: .
>  Factors of 6: 23
>  Factors of 7: ..
>  Factors of 8:
>   2.4
>  Factors of 9: .3.
>  Factors of 10: 2..5
>  Factors of 11: ....
>  Factors of 12: 234.6
>  Factors of 13: .....
>   Factors of 14: 2....7
>  Factors of 15: .3.5..
>  Factors of 16:
>   2.4...8
>  Factors of 17: .......
>  Factors of 18: 23..6..9
>  Factors of 19: ........
>  Factors of 20: 2.45....10

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FinFac {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 2; i <100; i++) one:  {
         if (i%2 > 0 ) break one;
        System.out.print("Deliteli " + i + ": ");
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i == j) break;
            else if ((i % j) == 0)
        System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```